# "Thresholding" for Stream Raster

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Using ASTER DEM, I have created Flow Accumulation. However, to create stream order, I was asked to input flow accumultation and stream raster. But I cannot find how to get the stream raster. Some forums say that I should threshold flow accumulation. How do I do this? Please guide me in the right direction.

I am using ArcGIS 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ArcGIS 10, search the help for the topic *Identifying stream networks*. As you'll discover you need to use the CON tool.

Answer (score 1):

The help file entries for [Hydrologic Analysis](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Understanding_drainage_systems) are very good, and lead you step-by-step through the processes needed to create your stream network in ArcGIS.

If you follow these steps in order you should find the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How To extract streams and define basins From ASTER.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5T64dpFrZ2Y

Comment: Please add some context. Link only answers end up expiring and becoming useless over time.